# Bash script that would give out information about the desired directory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need a script that would be similar to the ls and dir commands. To display information about the needed directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for entry in *
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

But this script outputs files only in the directory where the script is located. How do I make the output in the directory that I need?

Comment: This script should output the files in the directory _where you run it_, not in the directory where the script lives. For example, if I put this script in my `~/bin` directory (which is on my path) and then I run it when my current dir is `/home/myaccount/somefiles` it will output a list of the files in the "somefiles" directory. Which is exactly what it did when I tried it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't know that I couldn't do it the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can accept args with `$1`, etc. and refer to them later

```sh
for file in "$1"; do
```

Comment: It still gives only the name of the folder itself, and not the name of the files inside

Comment: if you want to enumerate the contents of each member, you could directly loop again if the file is a directory `[[ -d "$test" ]]`, perhaps using a function if you wanted arbitrary depth!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I just need to output the file names in the right directory, but without using the ls and dir commands.

Comment: what is the right directory? how does your script know? are you running it like `sh myscript.sh target_directory`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I don't want to constantly move the script from one directory to another. I want to specify exactly which directory files to output when running the script

Answer (score 0):

This APP provides a better way to learn and understand unix/linux. I would like to suggest you to take a look.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kanha.unixlinuxpocketbook

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for entry in /dir/I-need/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

also may be you would like

```
find /dir/I-need
```